# Sabre QueueAccessLLSRQ 9999 page limit

Tags: sabre

Hi we use the QueueIdentifier form of QueueAccessLLSRQ to access the list of bookings on a queue.

If the Queue contains less than 9999 bookings then the full list of bookings is available, however, if there are more than 9999 bookings on the queue then the first 9999 only are listed.

If a second call is then made for the same queue the same list of bookings is returned. In order to retrieve the remainder, next 9999 items, of the queue the first 9999 need to be removed.

The question I have is whether it is possible, without removing bookings from the queue to page through the queue to get the full list of bookings?

Regards and Thanks

Bruce